# UUID and string conversion

Tags: uuid

I am not sure if my understanding is correct. An arbitrary string can be converted to UUID, and able to convert back from the UUID to the original string (just like encryption/decryption). Is it true? If so, what are the conversion rules? It seems this twiki does not have too much information => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3):

No,that is not true.  You can generate a UUID from an arbitrary string (i.e. a version 3 "name-based" UUID), as described in [Section 4.3 of RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.3), however this is not reversible.  The MD5 and SHA-1 algorithms used to hash the strings are one-way hashes.  They are, by design, not reversible so there's no way to recover the original string from which a UUID is generated (unless you cache the hash->string mapping somewhere else).